# SQL Server chooses inefficient plan (via EntityFramework)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

sorry for the lengthy post, kind of hard to describe the issue without pictures. Plainly put, SQL is using different query plans for the same query (depending on whether I use parameters or not). I understand this is an issue with parameter sniffing, but as I'm using Entity Framework, I don't have a way to use hints for my queries.

## Table Design

Here is a picture of the table setup (I only use a few fields in this example)

[image: database]

#### Example Query

```
    SELECT TOP 10 * FROM MarketItems mk
    JOIN ItemAttributes attr ON mk.TypeId == attr.Id
    WHERE attr.Name LIKE '%item_name%' AND Expired = 0
    ORDER BY mk.LastSeen DESC
```

#### Market Items Table description:

Both TypeID and LastSeen are indexed. Expired is a bit field. 
On average, there are roughly ~40,000 items that are NOT expired, and ~4mil + expired (which shouldn't even matter).

#### Item Attributes Table description:

For the item attributes table, only the primary key (Id) is indexed, and there are approximately ~20,000 records.

## The Issue

This occurs when EF uses a parameter in the query and it takes over 6 seconds to query empty data, where it should normally be nearly instant. Even if I search for a non-exitant name in the attributes table, it takes roughly 6 seconds for the query to complete. It seems like it's going through ALL the Market Items, and doing a text lookup in the Attributes table every time.

#### The Bad Execution Plan

Here is the query plan with parameters (which takes 6-7s to run for no data)

Full res link: https://puu.sh/8fNKy/2a98367722.png

[image: bad_plan]

#### The Good Execution Plan

Here is exact same query without parameters (which of course, runs instantly for any string or item):

Full res link: https://puu.sh/8fNSH/6c6f7039fe.png
[image: good_plan]

So, the question is either why does SQL generate such a bad plan, or how can I force EF (6.1) to use a different plan or accept query hints. 
I'm open to any other suggestions as to how I can resolve this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried turning on force adhoc parameterisation and benchmarking? Have you ensured your statistics are up to date?

Comment: Yes, I rebuilt all indexes, and updated all statistics. I'll look into adhoc parameterisation and bechmarking right now

Comment: Also: WHERE attr.Name LIKE '%item_name%' will probably preclude the use of any available index.

Comment: Is Name an Nvarchar column?

Comment: Yes it is, that shouldn't make a difference, should it? There's only 20k records or so that it has to search through

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very hard to make assumptions of any merrit on why the optimizer producet this or that plan without the full XML of the execution plan, along with the relevant statistics.

However, you also asked how to force use of a particular plan, and for this there is an answer.

Use plan guides to tell optimizer what to do. With a plan guide for a specific query you can specify certain optimizer hints or even the whole execution plan. If there is a good plan in the cache it is very easy to fix it with a plan guide.

This is all very well explained in books online:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179880.aspx

You can also turn forced parameterization on, but be careful with this and test thoroughly, because it's database-wide setting and affects every query, for good or for bad.